# There exists infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n)$ is a prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found in a number theory book the following lines

Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients such that none of the following hold for it

1) There is an integer $d>1$ such that $d|f(n)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$
2) $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Then it is conjectured that there exists infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n)$ is a prime.
If deg$(f)=1$ we get Dirichlet's Theorem

The book is not a really new one so I wanted to know if this is still open or has been solved. In any case please share some links for more information on it.

Comment: Since you said "...none of the following hold for it...", shouldn't 2 be "$f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$"

Answer (score 3):

This is known as [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), and as far as I know, almost no progress has been made on it. In fact, we don't even know if $p(n)=n^2+1$ produces infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Alex R.'s answer, this conjecture is further generalized by the Bateman-Horn conjecture, which not only predicts infinitely many primes for polynomials, but it also predicts the *asymptotic density* of primes, not only for an individual polynomial, but even if you require multiple polynomials to be *simultaneously* prime.  Again, almost no progress has been made on this conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

Add a little culture, given integers $a,b,c$ with, say, $a > 0,$ $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $b^2 - 4 a c $ not zero or one or a square, then
$$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 $$
takes on infinitely many prime values. Just that it takes two variables to accomplish that. If  $b^2 - 4 a c < 0,$ the form is positive definite. If  $b^2 - 4 a c > 0,$ the form is indefinite; it can sometimes be extremely difficult to say which (positive) primes $p$ can be expressed as $ p = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, $ and for which we have instead $ -p = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2. $